# Why did the ancient Greeks choose tetrachords?

Tags: theory, chords, scales, chord-theory, tetrachords

Why did the ancient Greeks choose tetrachords as the basis for their musical theory rather than some other structure?

Comment: Be warned, questions like this can be impossible to answer -- often there's no particular reason *why* a culture develops its musical thinking a certain way rather than all the other ways it could have. But I'm no classicist so don't be put off, there may be an established answer out there...